# Auto Update markers if database was changed or records were added

Tags: android, arraylist, markers

```
  public class Viewmap extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener,OnMarkerClickListener      
 {
   // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<LatLng> Points;
    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://192.168.254.107/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_LAT = "lat";
    private static final String TAG_LNG = "lng";
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewmap);

 // Hashmap for ListView

        Points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());
    // Getting Google Play availability status

    // Showing status
    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    }else { // Google Play Services are available

         // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
        googleMap = fm.getMap();
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);

        new LoadAllProducts().execute();         

     // Loading products in Background Thread


    }
  }

private void DrawMarker(LatLng point){
    String add = "";
    // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

    // Setting latitude and longitude for the marker
    markerOptions.position(point);

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(Viewmap.this,
            Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(point.latitude,
                point.longitude, 1);
        add = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + "," + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + "," + 
                addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2)+","+addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(3);

        }

    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        // Adding marker on the Google Map
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions
                .title("Click here to do desired action")
                .snippet(add));


}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Viewmap.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();


    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    // getting JSON string from URL
                    JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

                    // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                    Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

                    try {
                        // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                        if (success == 1) {
                            // products found
                            // Getting Array of Products
                            products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                            // looping through All Products
                            for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                                // Storing each json item in variable
                                String LAT = c.getString(TAG_LAT);
                                String LNG = c.getString(TAG_LNG);

                                double lat = Double.valueOf(LAT);
                                double lng = Double.valueOf(LNG);              


                                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);



                                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                                Points.add(position);
                            }
                        } else {
                            // no products found
                            // Launch Add New product Activity
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    NewProductActivity.class);
                            // Closing all previous activities
                            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return null;
                }

                /**
                 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
                 * **/
                protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                    // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                if(Points.size()>0) {
                        for(LatLng point: Points) { 
                            DrawMarker(point); 
                            } }


                }

            }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
     // Setting the zoom level in the map on last position  is clicked

}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

        return false;
       }
   }
```

I want to call again the `AsyncTask` if the `DataBase` was recently changed or another record was added.. I cant seem to find any codes that will solve this problem .. Basically this is AutoUpdate if the `DataBase` was changed

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want communication with server that to down link. Every time the server database is updated by location you need the response.

At very beginning or simple level you can use of GCM. Every time the server DB get updated generate a push from server to update your map on device.

But if the frequency of location change is more, you have to write some logic to have minimum location change occur before generating a push from server .